# Limits for executing queries with cron job

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I never did cron job so I want to know few things before getting into it.
Site where it needs to be done is not high traffic site but it works in a way that user does search and if search doesnt have hits then search parameters can be saved and every 30min that saved search is executing with cron job. If search finds hit then sms and email are sent to user.
This means that one user can have more searches saved so cron job will execute a lot of searches.
 Is it OK to do that this way? And if yes, is there some max number of table rows and queries that can be executed with cron job without server overload?

Comment: You need to be careful about storing search queries from users, and then running them every 30 minutes in a cron job.

Assuming you implement SQL Injection prevention mechanisms, you will still be storing search queries from bots and malicious users; over time that is going to be a whole lot of wasted space, let alone running useless queries every 30 minutes that may or may not break your site. What is the problem you are trying to solve? could you be more specific? Why is searching user queries every 30 minutes really necessary?

Comment: @AlanChavez user can save search or not. Parameters are not saved for every search. It is option just for logged in users and when parameters are found and sms/email sent that search is not active anymore